# How would I extract a specific sentence from a website using preg match?

Tags: php, html

How would I use `preg_match` to extract a sentence from a website?

```
file_get_contents('http://link.com');
preg_match('/\Name of the day is\/', $page, $matches);
```

I want to extract ONLY the sentence that contains "Name of the day is" and show that sentence.

Answer (score 0):

```
$page = file_get_contents('http://link.com');
$regex = '/Name of the day is (\w+)/'
preg_match($regex, $page, $matches);
```

See http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/24q to tweak if needed.